# Consistent DNS query timeut for TXT records in Azure Linux VM

Tags: email-server, dkim, opensuse

I am running dkimproxy to sign and validate mail.

I have been always getting this error when receiving mail. I never fixed it since years but now I would like to get rid of this

```
Dec 11 13:44:54 cole dkimproxy.in[1193]: DKIM verify - invalid (public key: DNS query timeout for me._domainkey.booking.com at /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.18.1/Mail/DKIM/DNS.pm line 156, <_GEN_1> line 492.); message-id=<[....]@memta-103.ams4.prod.booking.com>, signer=<@booking.com>, sender=<noreply@booking.com>
```

This is consistent with every sender. It does not look like a network problem because the following command can be run by root (running as `dkim` user)

```
cole:/etc/postfix # sudo -u dkim dig -t txt me._domainkey.booking.com

; <<>> DiG 9.9.4-rpz2.13269.14-P2 <<>> -t txt me._domainkey.booking.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 56435
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 1280
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;me._domainkey.booking.com. IN  TXT

;; ANSWER SECTION:
me._domainkey.booking.com. 561  IN  TXT "v=DKIM1\; k=rsa\; p=MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQCX77HQTdkvsMtO6SZdke7uJuSuoEiw/bs/Om+60HHEwspP3FUhJeud289ousFt/g7R9BSrOuInUlnlx8BtMQsX6izI7iakIvxNpzrMt1XEZGm/j7KWOsEa3QxvZQbB0qNu28GeSlDCGYiYBZ0GfA/nsqKqByQ/RA/kswr6QzuMOwIDAQAB"

;; Query time: 1 msec
;; SERVER: 10.110.104.7#53(10.110.104.7)
;; WHEN: Mon Dec 11 13:47:07 CET 2017
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 301
```

dkimproxy version is 1.4.1-8.1.1

```
cole:/usr/share/dkimproxy/bin # zypper if dkimproxy
Lettura dei dati del repository in corso...
Lettura dei pacchetti installati in corso...


Informazioni per pacchetto dkimproxy:
-------------------------------------
Repository: @System
Nome: dkimproxy
Versione: 1.4.1-8.1.1
Arch: noarch
Fornitore: openSUSE
Installato: SÃ¬
Stato: aggiornato
Dimensione installata: 150,2 KiB
Sommario: DKIMproxy is an SMTP-proxy that implements the DKIM and DomainKeys standards
Descrizione: 
DKIMproxy is an SMTP-proxy that signs and/or verifies emails, using the
Mail::DKIM module. It is designed for Postfix, but should work with any
mail server. It comprises two separate proxies, an "outbound" proxy for
signing outgoing email, and an "inbound" proxy for verifying signatures
of incoming email. With Postfix, the proxies can operate as either
Before-Queue or After-Queue content filters.
```

How can I get this fixed?

Comment: Are you sure DKIM runs the exact same command as you think? Maybe try to sniff its DNS traffic. As for your manual command I note in the reply that it used EDNS because of the large UDP packets, that may be a problem for dkimproxy. Does it fail for all DNS queries?

Comment: DKIM uses a Perl function to query the DNS, not dig. My thought is that EDNS is not supported by `/usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.18.1/Mail/DKIM/DNS.pm`. I used dig as the best option to verify absence of network problems